# Connecting Website to Azure SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, azure, html-table

I've been trying to get my website to connect to an Azure SQL Database for a hot minute now. On my personal computer, I have XAMP set up with the drivers(I think). Here is the code:

```
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Link</th>
                <th scope="col">Assigned to</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
            </tr>
            <?php

            // SQL Server Extension Sample Code:
            $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "*****", "pwd" => "*******", "Database" => "SAND", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);
            $serverName = "tcp:myfsusqlserver.database.windows.net,1433";
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


            $selected = mysql_select_db('SAND', $conn); //select db
            $viewQuery = "select * from dbo.LINK join dbo.CUSTOMER";
            $execute = mysql_query($viewQuery);
            while($dataRows=mysql_fetch_array($execute))
            {
                $url = $dataRows['URL'];
                $email = $dataRows['CUSTOMER_ID'];
                $cat = $dataRows['CAT_ID'];
                
            }?> 
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $url; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cat; ?></td>

            </tr>
            </table>
           ?php>
```

If someone could help me figure out my issue, that would be greatly appreciated.

Quick Update:

It gave me this Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> sqlsrv_connect() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BUILDERSEXCHANGEWEBSITE\index.php:67 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\BUILDERSEXCHANGEWEBSITE\index.php on
> line 67

Comment: It seems you use the wrong method. To connect to an Azure SQL or Any SQL server using PHP, you should install the **required drivers** based on your operating system. You could choose **SQLSRV** driver or **PDO** driver.

Comment: `sqlsrv_connect` is part of PHP Driver for SQL Server. You need to download and install this driver and change all `mysql_` function calls with the appropriate functions from the installed driver (`sqlsrv_` functions). And, of course, using `PDO` is probably the best option here.

Comment: I'm attempting to install the PHP drivers on Xampp and am opening phpInfo on the dashboard, but I don't see it...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not proper for Azure SQL Database.

Use this sample [connect to Azure SQL DB and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-php):

```
<?php
    $serverName = "your_server.database.windows.net"; // update me
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "your_database", // update me
        "Uid" => "your_username", // update me
        "PWD" => "your_password" // update me
    );
    //Establishes the connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    $tsql= "SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName
         FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc
         JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p
         ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid";
    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    echo ("Reading data from table" . PHP_EOL);
    if ($getResults == FALSE)
        echo (sqlsrv_errors());
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo ($row['CategoryName'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . PHP_EOL);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
?>
```